# Point of inversion of the center of a circle with regard of another circle.

Tags: geometry, circles

If a circle $L$ with center $A$ and radius $r$ cuts the circle $K$ with center $O$ and radius $k$, and we know that $k^2+r^2=|OA|^2$, prove that the inverse point of $A$ with regard of $K$ is the middle point of the common chord of $K$ and $L$

The only thing I can come up to is to use the tangential points, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The middle point of the common chord of both circles is $M$. For $M$ to be the inverse point of $A$ with regards to circle $K$ (the circle with center $O$) -

we need to prove (i) points $A, M, O$ are collinear and (ii) $OA.OM = k^2$ ($k$ is the radius of circle $K$).

As it is common chord, the perpendicular from $A$ and $O$ will meet the chord at mid point. So, $A, M, O$ are collinear.

It is given that $k^2 + r^2 = |OA|^2$ which means $\triangle ADO$ is a right angled triangle (as $AD = r$, $DO = k$).

Now please note $\angle DAO = 90^0 - \angle DOA = \angle MDO$.

So $\triangle ADM \sim \triangle DOM$

$\frac {MD} {AD} = \frac {OM}{OD}$ and $\frac {AM} {AD} = \frac {MD}{OD}$

So, we get $MD = \frac{r}{k} OM = \frac{k}{r} AM$

$AM = OA - OM = \frac{r^2}{k^2} OM$

$OM = \frac{k^2 \, OA}{k^2+r^2}$

$OA.OM = \frac{k^2 \, {(OA)}^2}{k^2+r^2} = k^2$

Comment: Sorry for the out of context question, where did you make that figure?

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry